# how to use fscanf in c to read formated data from a file

Tags: c, scanf

i want to read these data and put them to a array of struct but it does not work

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct book {
    char bookName[50];
    char authorName[50];
    long price;
    int year;
}
main() {
    FILE *data;
    data=fopen("library.txt", "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("File Could not be opened!\n");
    }
    else {
        struct book myBook;
        struct book books[20];

        int n=0;

        while (!feof(data))
        {
            fscanf(data,"%s***%s***%d***%d\n",&myBook.bookName,&myBook.authorName,&myBook.price,&myBook.year);
            books[n]=myBook;
            n++;
        }

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%s - %s - %d - %d \n",books[i].bookName,books[i].authorName,books[i].price,books[i].year);
        }
    }
}
```

and output is

```
C - b - 0 - 232159429
programing***Fatemeh - b - 0 - 232159429
Kazemi***15000***1391 - b - 0 - 232159429
C - b - 0 - 232159429
programs***Ali - b - 0 - 232159429
Ahmadpour***20000***1392 - b - 0 - 232159429
Programing***Mona - b - 0 - 232159429
Ghassemi***25000***1389 - b - 0 - 232159429
C - b - 0 - 232159429
programing - b - 0 - 232159429
(advanced)***Sara - b - 0 - 232159429
Hamidi***40000***1385 - b - 0 - 232159429
```

but my real data is

```
C programing***Fatemeh Kazemi***15000***1391
Cprograms***Ali Ahmadpour***20000***1392
Programing***Mona Ghassemi***25000***1389
C programing (advanced)***Sara Hamidi***40000***1385
```

what should i do?
it looks fscanf only works with spaces but i need to use *** to seperate my data

Comment: One major problem is that the `"%s"` format reads *space delimited* strings. Another problem is that you [should not use `feof()` in a loop condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). A third problem is that you don't check what [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*. A fourth is that you should not use the address-of operator `&` (as in `&myBook.bookName`) for arrays.

Comment: @usr2564301 Not outside a format specifier. `*` in a format string is to match a literal `*` in the input, but e.g. `"%*s"` is something completely different.

Comment: fscanf(data,"%s***%s***%d***%d\n",&myBook.bookName,&myBook.authorName,&myBook.price,&myBook.year);

Comment: what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Stop trying to do this with scanf.

Comment: and use what? fgets?

Comment: If you have asterisks in the data separating fields, use `%49[^*]` to read up to the asterisks, at least for the string-valued fields.

Comment: Can a book name contain a `*` or two? Like `"C**programing***Fatemeh Kazemi***15000***1391"`?

Comment: What should happen with book names exceeding 50 characters?

Comment: book names don't excee 50 characters by default

Comment: user:15168 how can i use that?

Comment: Why are you not using CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `fscanf()`.  The error checking is too difficult or incomplete.

`while (!feof(data))` does not insure the the following read will be successful.

```
// while (!feof(data)){  
//  fscanf(data,"%s***%s***%d***%d\n",....
```

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of file input and then parse.

```
size_t n = 0;
// Work with an ample sized buffer
char buf[sizeof (struct book) * 2];
while (n < 20 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, data)) {
```

Now parse the data looking for `"***"`

```
  char *sep[3];
  sep[0] = strstr(buf, "***");
  if (sep[0] == NULL) break;
  sep[1] = strstr(sep[0] + 3, "***");
  if (sep[1] == NULL) break;
  sep[2] = strstr(sep[1] + 3, "***");
  if (sep[2] == NULL) break;
```

Let us pre-fill `myBook` with zeros - useful for debugging and insure null characters for the strings.

```
  struct book myBook;
```

Insure separators are not too far apart

```
  if (sep[0] - buf >= sizeof myBook.bookName) break;
  memcpy(myBook.bookName, buf, sep[0] - buf);    //
  if (sep[1] - sep[0] - 3 >= sizeof myBook.authorName) break;   
  memcpy(myBook.authorName, sep[0] + 3, sep[1] - sep[0] - 3);
```

Use `atol()` or ...

```
  myBook.price = atol(sep[1] + 3);
```

... `strtol()`, or `sscanf()` for more error checking.  Maybe check for valid year values?

```
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  myBook.year = strtol(sep[2] + 3, &endptr, 10);
  if (sep[2] + 3 == endptr) break;
  if (errno) break;
  if (myBook.year < year_MIN || myBook.year > year_MAX) break;
```

Ok, code made it

```
   books[n] = myBook;
   n++;      
 }
```

---

> but i need to use *** to separate my data

If `"*"` and  `"**"` never occur, code could use the following which has less error checking.  Always check the return values of input functions.

```
while (n < 20 && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, data)) {
  if (sscanf(buf, "%49[^*]***%49[^*]***%ld***%d",
      myBook.bookName, myBook.authorName, &myBook.price, &myBook.year) != 4) {
    break;  // badly formatted data
  }
  books[n] = myBook;
  n++;      
}
```

Comment: @ali I am curious why you coded `while (!feof(data))`. Who or what text suggested that?

Comment: user:2410359 it is a piece of solution from another question written by my university professor

Comment: @ali run for your life.

Answer (score 0):

This program reads your data in the current format and produces the output as '-' delimited entries (as in the printf statement you provided):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF 500

int parse_string(char* s,char* a[]);

struct book {
    char bookName[50];
    char authorName[50];
    long price;
    int year;
};

int main() {

    FILE *data;
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    char *sp, *words[MAXBUF];
    int nw;

    data=fopen("library.txt", "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("File Could not be opened!\n");
    }
    else {
        struct book myBook;
        struct book books[20];

        int n=0;

        // Read each line into buf and parse it into words, 
        // assign words into structure fields   
        while((sp = fgets(buf, MAXBUF, data))!= NULL){
            nw=parse_string(buf, words);

            // If number of words different than number of
            // fields in the structure exit with an error
            if (nw!=4){
                printf("Error - number of parsed words does not match number of fields in the structure!\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            // Assign values, convert strings to long and int
            strncpy(myBook.bookName, words[0], strlen(words[0])+1);
            strncpy(myBook.authorName, words[1], strlen(words[1])+1);

            myBook.price = atol(words[2]);
            myBook.year = atoi(words[3]);

            // Add to book array
            books[n] = myBook;

            n++;
        }

       // Print 
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
           printf("%s - %s - %ld - %d \n",books[i].bookName,books[i].authorName,books[i].price,books[i].year);
       }
    }
}


/* Function to parse a line of input into an aray of words */
/* s - pointer to the char array (line) to be parsed
 * a - array of pointers to parsed elements 
 * returns number of elements in a*/
int parse_string(char* s, char* a[])
{
    int nw,j;
    a[0] = strtok(s,"*\t\n\r\v\f");
    nw = 1;
    while((a[nw]= strtok(NULL,"*\t\n\r\v\f"))!=NULL)
        nw++;
    return nw;
}
```

Like suggested in the comments, this program uses `fgets` to read the file line at a time. It then uses a parsing function to parse each line into words based on given delimiters. The parsing function is small and uses `strtok` and hardcoded delimiter set. Based on your input, it does not use the space as a delimiter and instead uses the `*`. It allows for other delimiters like reasonably new lines and maybe not as reasonably tabs.

Next step is assignment of each word to its field in the `book` structure. This is preceded by a check whether the number of words return from the parsing function (`nw`) is equal to to the current number of fields). Finally, if it is - it assigns the members with any necessary conversions to `myBook` and adds this entry to book array.

Some improvements that can be left out as an exercise would be enabling command line argument with input file name rather than hardcoding it. Writing the output to a file would also be good in which case output file would be the second command line argument. Finally, as mentioned in the comments you could and should provide some input size checking against the sizes of the arrays you are using.

Comment: A short coming to `strtok(s,"*\t\n\r\v\f");` is that a single `'*'` also acts as a field delimiter.

Comment: @chux true, but I assumed the OP wanted plain information in the output and that the `*` would not be the part of that information. It looks like the OP is using `*` instead of a space to allow for space-separated names in his fields which makes sense.

Comment: @ali glad to help, this is the way I would normally do it for myself. If you have any questions about the details of this code, feel free to ask, I'll add them to the answer. Study the pieces in detail, they will be useful in the future.

Comment: @ali can the book name really contain a `*` in it? if that's the case then this will need some changes.

Comment: there is no * in the default data of the question , and nothing is mentioned

Comment: i have a question . what does the s parameter do in the parse_string function

Comment: ok, I got confused when re-reading the comments under your question. To me it seems you answered to @chux that it is possible - if it is not, consider deleting that comment and answering with no or even add it to your question.

Comment: s is the line from file you are parsing, it is a pointer to a string/char array. The particular way it is parsed is a common usage of strtok. I can explain but you can also look it up easily and find some explanation to your liking.